# Resize a small image to get the text from it using python

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library, ocr, opencv, python

I'm new to image processing libraries in python, currently i'm failing trying to get a text from a small image 147x15 with a transparent background. One way to perform that is to resize the image by making it bigger and trying not to loose quality so it can be well interpreted, there is the original image link:

(147x15)
https://www.lespagesmaghreb.com/generated/contact_methods/496321.png

This is my code to get the text from the image:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract 
from PIL import Image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread('img_new.png')
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print(text)
```

And there is the expected image (181 x 80) output which works with the previous code (manually edited)

[image]

How can I perform that automatically ? thanks.

**EDIT:**

I tried to resize the image to 200%  of it's current size, the result is a black image, this is the used code:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img_n.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

print('Original Dimensions : ',img.shape)

scale_percent = 200 # percent of original size
width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
# resize image
resized = cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

print('Resized Dimensions : ',resized.shape)

cv2.imshow("Resized image", resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the image:

[image]

Comment: I think `cv2.resize(img, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)` may help, but check which interpolation gives best results in your case [link](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/)

Comment: @BelalHomaidan I tried it and it's giving me a black image only, what could be the issue ?

Comment: can you please check the values and the type of your images? `print(type(image), image.max())`, and tell the result?

Comment: @BelalHomaidan the result is : <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 0

Comment: @BelalHomaidan this is for the resize code : <class 'numpy.ndarray'> 255

Comment: add this line after you read the image directly `img = img[:,:,3]`, so you can see the image.

Comment: @BelalHomaidan it's working good, for the resize and printing the text from the image, can you provide some explanation about the issue and the solution ?

Comment: @BelalHomaidan can you provide some documentation to read ?

Comment: Digital Image Processing (4th Edition) 
by Rafael C. Gonzalez, Richard E. Woods